# How can I edit the columns of multiple files in the same folder then overwriting it?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I am at the edge of frustration thats why my way of explain myself might be rough.

I am trying to remove a column from a tab delimited text files. I have 10 files with same pattern of names such as (written below), thats why when I use such commands like cut I get frustrated with using tab many times.

So my questions;

1) Is there a easier method of basically copying the file name for overwriting?
cut -f 1,3 oldfile.txt > oldfile.txt

btw when I do the method above, my all lines got erased for some reason.

2) Since I dont know the regular expression well enough, is there a way to go around of awk ? that language seems pretty complicated for me.
3)What is the most memory efficient method for his task? Please tell me a method then I will learn that method even its as hard as learning Chinese.

I am a unix frasturared mediocare. sorry for my bad england.

Best regards,

file name example: KKK12398801_normal_912839.txt

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using awk. It's a nice tool for when you want to manipulate data by column.

Comment: Your lines with your solution 1) get erased since you are overwriting the inputfile with the output. You will need a temp file, or use `sed` with option `-i` (when available) or `ed` (memory efficient, harder to learn).